# insert edittext between two other edittexts with inflater

Tags: android

I am totally new to android and programming, and you have helped me a ton so far. I have hit another roadblock,however. (sure there are many more to come)

I am adding edittexts dynamically with the layoutinflator to a vertical linearlayout.

When i select an edittext in the middle and  hit the button to inflate another edittext, I need to know how to insert the new edittext directly below the one that is selected, pushing the rest down, instead of adding it after the last one added.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinearLayout has an [addView(View view, int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) method which you can use to put new view into it at specific position.

Comment: Wow, this sounds exactly like what I need. It would be doubly awesome if someone could tell me how to get the index of selected item, so I know where to pu the inserted edittext.

Comment: That's the harder part i was hoping you already have :O) One idea though (i'm sure others will come up with better ones): how about going through the LinearView's children using `getChildAt(int)` and checking which of them is the one selected? You can check for the EditText's `isSelected()` flag?, or check a tag you set when you select it (using `setTag("hey_it's_me!")`)...

Comment: sounds like the right track. I accepted this as the answer. will post back and vote when i figure it out the rest of the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have a empty LinearLayout between the two, to where you inflate.

This is if you only have 2.

If it's really dynamic go with @compostus answer.

Comment: so you're saying add an empty LinearLayout with every edittext I add?

Comment: sounds like it would get messy with possibly tons of nested layouts, If I added an edittext to the empty layout, it would have its own empty layout attached to accept inserts, and so on.